# ActiveRecord query for count of association using a join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working an events feature, and I'm running into a rather involved query.

Here's the models for reference:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :party

  belongs_to :host, foreign_key: :host_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :convention, optional: true
  has_many :join_requests
  
  ...
end
```

I'm looking to check which Events are accepting members, by checking the `member_limit` of the associated Party.

```
class Party < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :host, foreign_key: :host_id, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :user_parties
  has_many :members, through: :user_parties, source: 'user'

  ...
end
```

`Party` has an integer column: `member_limit` -- which only allows a set amount of party members.

So far I have a scope on Event that looks like this:

```
scope :accepting_members, -> () do
    joins(party: :user_parties).group('parties.member_limit').select('count(user_parties.user_id) < parties.member_limit')
  end
```

Which doesn't work too well.

Am I on the right track?

I tried using the COUNT() aggregate, but it only returns a hash of integers.

Comment: You're not really on the right track. There are various approaches here like using `WHERE events.id IN (subquery)` where the subquery gets the event ids, `WHERE EXISTS(subquery)` or by using a lateral join.

Comment: The reason your approach won't work is that the group on `parties.member_limit`  and select clause will apply to the entire query and you won't get anywhere near the actual result you want which is rows off the events table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a bit more complicated then you initially thought if you want usable output and there are quite a few ways to do this.

One way is to create a subquery for the event ids:

```sql
SELECT events.* 
FROM events
WHERE events.id IN (
  SELECT parties.events_id
  FROM parties
  OUTER LEFT JOIN user_parties ON parties.id = user_parties.party_id
  GROUP BY parties.event_id
  HAVING(
    COUNT(user_parties.user_id) < parties.member_limit
  )
)
```

Writing this in ActiveRecord/Arel gets a bit hairy:

```
subquery = Party.select(:events_id)
                .left_joins(:user_parties)
                .group(:event_id)
                .having(
                  # COUNT(user_parties.user_id) < parties.member_limit
                  UserParty.arel_table[:user_id].count.lt(
                    Party.arel_table[:member_limit]
                  )
                )
                .where(
                  # events.id = parties.event_id
                  Event.arel_table[:id].eq(Party.arel_table[:id])
                )
 
Event.where(
  id: subquery
)
```

Other ways to do this would be to use `EXIST` or a lateral join.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need any complex joins you can do it like this.

Since relation is as follows

1. Event has_one Party
2. Party has_many UserParty

You can do it like this.

```
# event.rb
scope :accepting_members, -> { party.user_parties.count < party.member_limit }
```

This will return boolean. if member limit is not reached it will return true otherwise false.

Comment: This is not a good answer. If this code actually did work it would both cause a N+1 query and require you to load the entire table.